# What does "Select Distinct Null As xxxxx" mean?

Tags: java, sql, database, stored-procedures, sybase

**Background:** I am mapping Sybase stored procedure return values to java objects using Spring.

For example I map a Sybase datatype of `varchar` as a `String` type in Java, and a Sybase datatype of `int` as an `int` type in Java, etc.

I have come across the following code in one of the stored procedures:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.Col1 AS val1,
    A.Col2 AS val2,
    NULL AS someVal,
    A.col3 AS val3,
    ...
    A.col9 AS val9
FROM #SomeTable A
ORDER BY Col2, Col3
```

I have 2 related questions:

1. What does `Null` mean in this scenario? I am confused as to what is happening here.
2. I am able to determine the data type of Col1, Col2, etc. of course by looking at the table definition of Table A defined earlier in the stored procedure.  Thus I know what datatype I can define in my Java object for val1, val2, etc..  But what about "someVal"? What datatype mapping am I supposed to perform for this Null value?

I am fairly inexperienced in SQL.  Perhaps the answer is much simpler than I realize.

Comment: You will have a column called `someVal` with `NULL` as the value for each row.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - What datatype in Java then will someVal be? String, int, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have a column called `someVal` with `NULL` as the value for each row.

With a `ResultSet`, you can use `getString(int)` or `getString(String)` which states

> **Returns**: the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value
>   returned is null

You can choose any reference type you want, including `Void`, to map this column. Or don't use any, ie. don't map it. Depends on your requirement.

Comment: This answers the first AND second question.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation you referenced in the post please?

Comment: @SoylentGreen Sorry, I was away. [Here's the javadoc for `ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)). As for `SELECT NULL`, I can't find any documentation but you can try it. It's just an available SQL feature.

Answer (score 3):

This creates a column with `NULL` values in all rows. This trick is useful when

- The reader of your query results expects a column `someVal` to be there, treating situations when this column is missing as errors, or
- Your query is part of a `UNION ALL` query inside a `GROUP BY` query, with other queries filling in values for `NULL`s.

Here is an example of the later situation:

```
SELECT -- This query flattens the results of the two sub-queries
    document_id
,   MIN(approval_date) as approval_date
,   MIN(availability_date) as availability_date
FROM (
    SELECT -- This subquery supplies approval_date
        document_id
    ,   MAX(approval_date) AS approval_date
    ,   NULL AS availability_date
    FROM document_approvals
    GROUP BY document_id
UNION ALL
    SELECT -- This subquery supplies availability_date
        document_id
    ,   NULL AS approval_date
    ,   MAX(availability_date) AS availability_date
    FROM document_approvals
    GROUP BY document_id
)
GROUP BY document_id
```